# Component in AEM console not activated

Tags: java, adobe, aem, crx

I have created a servlet class which will get called while making a ajax call.When seeing it from AEM console *system/console/components* ,its status is in **Factory** mode but it should have the status **Active** also.How to make the Component **Active** ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have attribute *configurationFactory = true* in your **@Component** annotation. It makes this class to behave as service factory and I believe put it here unintentionally, right? If you remove it - you will see **Active**.

Otherwise, If you need your servlet to be service factory, for some reason, you need to create named configuration for this factory.